# A bird-brained cipher

Tags: knowledge, cipher

Today my partner, an avid ornithologist who I swear spends his whole day looking at codes and tables online, left me this cryptic clue when I asked where he had been all day. He complained about a change from 6th to 7th edition of some checklist and how he stuck with 6th edition because he liked it better, but I never understand what he's on about. He can be a bit of a birdbrain, so hopefully one of you can help me figure out what he's talking about!

Where has he been?

> 4540 (2) 0431 (2) 4610 (2) 8506 (2) 3980 (2) 5332 (1)

Comment: If this goes into the direction I think it does, rot13(ner lbh fher gur fvkgu rqvgvba vf serryl ninvynoyr bayvar ba aba-fxrgpul jrofvgrf? V pna bayl frrz gb svaq gur arjrfg irefvbaf bs cbffvoyr pnaqvqngr yvfgf.)

Comment: @LukasRotter The sixth edition numerical table was available freely on a government website, so I figured it would be okay to use as a reference for the puzzle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your partner is:

> (not surprisingly) AT THE AVIARY

Reasoning:

> There are several references to birding and birding checklists, and a quick Google search reveals two main birding checklists: the AOU (American Ornithological Union) and ABA (American Birding Association) versions. The AOU (now AOS, American Ornithological Society) version went through a somewhat controversial migration from version 6 to version 7, which included dropping numerical codes for bird species from version 6. With some digging, there is an [online reference](https://www.pwrc.usgs.gov/bbl/manual/speclist.cfm) which gives a list of these numbers. Looking up the numbers in the given cipher yields
>
>  4540 = Ash-Throated Flycatcher
>  0431 = Thayer's Gull
>  4610 = Eastern Wood-Pewee
>  8506 = Victoria Penguin
>  3980 = Arizona Woodpecker
>  5332 = Yellow-fronted canary
>
>  To extract the message however, you do not need the common names of the birds, but rather the four-letter alpha codes associated with each:
>
>  4540 = ATFL
>  0431 = THGU
>  4610 = EAWP
>  8506 = VIPE
>  3980 = ARWO
>  5332 = YFCA
>
>  Finally, the numbers in parentheses behind each code indicate the number of letters to extract from each code, yielding the answer AT THE AVIARY.

Comment: +1 for 'migration' ;-) (and the solve of course!)

Comment: This is it, excellent job! :)