# Another bird-brained puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

[A few days ago, this lovely community helped me track down my ornithologist birdbrain of a partner.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102038/a-bird-brained-cipher) Today, I've lost him again, and it might be a little tougher to find him! After all, he’s very flighty. <sub>I’ll let myself out.</sub>

This time, he took a bunch of vacation days at work and disappeared overnight, and left me a note:

> Mick,
>
> See if you can find me this time – I went somewhere a little more exotic. When you've followed all the clues, take the first letter of each answer you find (in English, of course). *Kaló taksídi!*
>
> P.S. If you have trouble finding me, I'll text you some pictures of the birds here! <3

Below that was a list of birds and some symbols:

> **Rosy-throated longclaw**
>
> ↑ ↑ ↓ (MO) ↓ (CIT)
>
> **Yellow-throated leaflove**
>
> ↑ ↑ ↓ (CH) ↓ (FL)
>
> **Spectacled cormorant**
>
> ↑ ↑ ↓ (M) ↓ (P)
>
> **Hooded vulture**
>
> ↑ ↑ ↓ (AC) ↓ (AC) ↓ (ETHROP)
>
> **Pesquet’s parrot**
>
> ↑ ↑ ↑ ↓ (PCU) ↓ (L) ↓ (V) ↓ (U)
>
> **White-bellied sea eagle**
>
> ↑ ↓ (P)

Where did my partner go this time? (And how much am I going to have to shell out for a plane ticket?)

*Text Message Clue #1: (12 hours elapsed)*

> [image: Common wood pigeon]
>  Found a common wood pigeon taking a little nap today! (They don't have these back home!) Did you know their Latin name is *Columba palumbus*, part of the *Columbidae* family? Super fascinating! Anyway, hope the hunt is going well!

Comment: I think there's a typo in the Hooded Vulture letters

Comment: @Mohirl ETHROP was intentional obfuscation so as not to make the puzzle solution obvious, as a bird/biology person would immediately catch on to ERYTHR as a taxonomical code.

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense. I wouldn't have had a clue - just happened to be struck by divine inspiration as I looked as the sidebar after I googled Rosy-throated longclaw. Great puzzle!

Comment: @Mohirl I'm really glad you liked it and thank you for solving it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My partner is in

> Cyprus

Based on the hint, I think I might have an idea on how to go about solving this

The hint points us towards

> The scientific classification of the bird,  consisting bottom up of Species / Genus / Family / Order / Class / Phylum  / Kingdom

Each line below the bird names begins with one or more up arrows, followed by one or more down arrows accompanied by some letters. I suspect that the up arrows

> Represent how far up the scientific classification we go from the Species

while the down arrows indicate we should

> Go back down a level, with the letters indicating which option we should choose

For example: Rosy-throated longclaw

> Kingdom: Animalia /Phylum: Chordata   / Class:   Aves / Order:   Passeriformes / Family: Motacillidae / Genus:   Macronyx / Species: M. ameliae

So we start with the:

> Species, then go up two level (two up arrows) to the [Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motacillidae).

We then

> Go down (MO) into the genus [Motacilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagtail). After that we need to go down again (CIT) which gives us the Citrine wagtail, Motacilla citreola.

We're told to take the first letter of each answer in English, so presumably that just means

> C (or possibly CW)

The rest of this could take some time.

Yellow-throated leaflove

↑ ↑ ↓ (CH) ↓ (FL)

> Passerine > Chlorocichla > Yellow-bellied greenbul (Chlorocichla flaviventris). Second letter = Y.

Spectacled cormorant

↑ ↑ ↓ (M) ↓ (P)

> Phalacrocoracidae > Microcarbo > Microcarbo pygmaeus = Pygmy Cormorant. So P.

Hooded vulture

↑ ↑ ↓ (AC) ↓ (AC) ↓ (ETHROP)

> Accipitridae > (AC) Accipitrinae > (AC) Accipiter > (ETHROP) Accipiter erythropus = Red-thighed sparrowhawk. Letter R. (Possible typo here with ETHROP?)

Pesquet’s parrot

↑ ↑ ↑ ↓ (PCU) ↓ (L) ↓ (V) ↓ (U)

> We go further up to the Order this time, Psittaciformes > (PCU) ??? (confirmed by OP, path should be  Psittaculidae (PCU).and from there down to Loriinae (L) and down to Vini (V). (U) then gives us    Vini ultramarina = Ultramarine lorikeet , thus U

White-bellied sea eagle

↑ ↓ (P)

> Only up one level to the Genus, Haliaeetus, then down (P) to     Haliaeetus pelagicus = Steller's sea eagle. Which gives us S.

So altogether, we have

> CYPR?S which, confirmed by the note wishing us good luck in Greek, indicates we're off to Cyprus

Comment: I apologize for confusion on Pesquet's, my intended path was down to Psittaculidae (PCU).and from there down to Loriinae (L) and down to Vini (V). However that may not have been clear since that taxonomy is confusing and sources disagree on it sometimes. Marking you as correct since you solved it, well done! :)

Comment: Ah thanks, only seeing your comments now. I'd used Wikipedia for the rest and figured there might be a better source that would make that one clearer. I'll edit it in for completeness